# Debugging AJAX caching in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I have a simple proof of concept that seems to be handling caching oddly. Here's the view:

```
<script>       
$('#clickToLoad').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/Home/AjaxCacheTest") %>?"
        , dataType: 'json'
            ,ifModified: true
            ,cache: true
        ,success: function(sourceData) {
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is linked to an action in the controller:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "none", Duration = 3000)]
public ContentResult AjaxCacheTest()
{
    return Content("0", "application/json");
}
```

I'd like to get a result with caching, however, it seems that AjaxCacheTest doesn't cache unless I request it on its own (that is, in a browser window, instead of AJAX).

Setting cache: true doesn't help. Setting ifModified: true does cause caching, but then it doesn't call the success function, so I can't use the results.

Are there any options that allow caching and still call the response callback?

UPDATE:
Thanks, forgot to add those. I'm testing with firebug and determining how caching is handled by a combination of looking at the response code (200 OK vs 302) and the response time for the request. This is all on Visual Studio's built in server (Cassini?).

Comment: What are you testing with? IIS? Cassini? Are you in debug mode (I mean the setting in web.config)? Have you checked the reqeust and response headers via a tool like FireBug or something similar? Please do add the answers to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how the caching in your scenario works. Suppose you define the following action

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "none", Duration = 5)]
public ActionResult AjaxCache()
{
    return Json(new { date = DateTime.Now }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you don't explicitly set the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.location.aspx) attribute it default to [OutputCacheLocation.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx) which means:

> The output cache can be located on the
>   browser client (where the request
>   originated), on a proxy server (or any
>   other server) participating in the
>   request, or on the server where the
>   request was processed. This value
>   corresponds to the
>   HttpCacheability.Public enumeration
>   value.

`Duration = 5` means that the contents will be cached for 5 seconds. Next you send ajax request:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("cache test", "AjaxCache") %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $.ajax({ url: this.href,
            success: function(json) {
                $('#result').html(json.date);
            }
        });        
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

If you click on the link twice during 5 seconds interval you will see that the result div will not change neither the server action will be hit but the `success` callback will always execute. The server sends the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=5
Expires: Fri, 26 Feb 2010 14:09:02 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Feb 2010 14:08:57 GMT
Vary: *
```

Comment: Looks like this is somewhat working...I had to upgrade to MVC 2 to try it, perhaps that had something to do with it. It's no longer sending 304s, just 200s. I'll do some more testing and figure it out later, thanks.

Comment: Yup, this works in MVC 2, don't know what was broken in MVC 1.

Just one warning; at least in my case, I had to add dataType: 'json' to the ajax call. Thanks!